# validating xml file using xsd schema in java

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I'm surfing the net for more than a hour, but I didn't get a view to validate xml file using XSD schema in java with dom parser. Can someone provide some pointers, like websites or references?

Answer (score 0):

Google "Xerces J"; you will find a number of DOM-interface examples in their sample-applications page.